# how to reboot modem with command in java

Tags: java, command-prompt

hi i want to reboot my adsl modem with command prompt in java . but cmd stopped when username is wanted and must be entered. what is problem?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExecuteShellComand
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        String tel = "telnet 192.168.1.1 23";
        String user = "admin";
        String pass = "admin";
        String reboot = "reboot";
        String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c"+tel+"/c"+user+"/c"+pass+"/c"+reboot;

        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    }
}
```

[image: when username must be entered]

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `command` variable after building it so you can verify it's what you expect?  It looks like you're doing `...telnet telnet...`

Comment: i edited my code  but still i have problem . how i can print command?

Comment: `System.out.println(command)`

Comment: i don't think command has problem. in **cmd** 'Connecting To 192.168.1.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
onnect failed'

Comment: You're assuming you are building the command correctly as a string.   Print out your command variable and *verify* it is the same thing as the command you are manually entering.

Comment: What is `/c` supposed to achieve?

Comment: /c is like enter. Is not ?

Answer (score 2):

You may also need a space between each of your arguments. The way it is typed you will send a command to the prompt that looks like:

```
cmd /c start cmd.exe /ctelnet 192.168.1.1 23/cadmin/cadmin/creboot
```

Add a System.out.println(command); after creating the string to see what is actually in the String.

Edit your code to the following:

```
String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe /c "+tel+" /c "+user+" /c "+pass+" /c "+reboot;
System.out.println(command);
```

Comment: Are you able to get any info from the telnet help page? It may be best to try to correct the command before trying to execute it in Java. Be sure the command is correct before continuing.

Comment: i think problem is _/c_ command . because when i execute **/c telnet 192.168.1.1 23**  in command prompt it get error `/c is not recognized as an internal or external command` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the user name and password and `reboot` command to the standard input (stdin) of the telnet command. To do this, create a process and then:

```
// You /probably/ don't need "cmd /c" here ...
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tel);

// Write to stdin of child, force flush after each line
// Yes, you need to get an OutputStream here ... it's connected to stdin of the child
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(child.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("admin");
out.println("admin");
out.println("reboot");
```

Note that you may have to read stdout while you're sending these commands to prevent the child process from blocking. For this, create a background thread. See this post: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2

Comment: i just tried your code but it didn't work. how i can read stdout ?

Comment: Please never use "didn't work" again ever in your life. It's a huge waste of time. I've added a link to code which shows how you have to read stdout. If that "doesn't work", then please tell us what you expected and what the code did instead (incl. error messages, stack traces, and every other bit of information that you have).